# Serialize QVariantMap as QByteArray with QDataStream

Tags: c++, qt, serialization

I need to serialize a `QVariantMap` as a `QByteArray`, and it seems like the appropriate way to do that is through `QDataStream`.  However, I'm having a lot of trouble doing so.  I'm not getting any errors, but it doesn't actually save anything to the byte array.

```
//Create a QVariantMap that has a key value pair
QVariantMap *myMap = new QVariantMap();
myMap->insert("MyKey","the value for MyKey");

// Serialize it to a QBiteArray using a QDataStream object
QByteArray byteArray;
QDataStream stream(&byteArray, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
//qDebug() << byteArray.toHex();  ==> "" (because byteArray is empty)
stream << myMap;
//qDebug() << byteArray.toHex(); ==> "01" (regardless of what the key/value/etc. was, it's always 01)
//Test whether I can read it out
QVariantMap inMap;
QDataStream inStream(&byteArray, QIODevice::ReadOnly);
instream >> inMap;
//qDebug() << inMap.keys();  ==> () (No keys are in the map)
```

So there are no errors or obvious failures, but it still doesn't actually put any values (except for 01--the size?) into ByteArray.  I've tried a number of variations on this theme, none with any different result (except for variations that just cause an error).

The only thing I've done that makes a difference is multiple "stream << myMap" lines, which sets the byteArray to "010101", for instance, if I repeat the line three times.  So every time I run "stream << myMap", I get one more "01".

I was concerned that I could have just had incorrect read code and the writing was fine, which is why I added the debug line that checks the hex code, and makes it clear that there are writing errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an error in your code. What you are sending to your `byteArray` is not a `QVariantMap`, it is a pointer to a `QVariantMap`. This is just sending an address to the array not the map data. This change `stream << (*myMap);` should work for you.

Following a working example:

```
QVariantMap myMap, inMap;
QByteArray mapData;

myMap.insert("Hello", 25);
myMap.insert("World", 20);

QDataStream outStream(&mapData, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
outStream << myMap;
qDebug() << myMap;
QDataStream inStream(&mapData, QIODevice::ReadOnly);
inStream >> inMap;
qDebug() << inMap;
```

**Output**

```
QMap(("Hello", QVariant(int, 25) ) ( "World" ,  QVariant(int, 20) ) ) 
QMap(("Hello", QVariant(int, 25) ) ( "World" ,  QVariant(int, 20) ) )
```

Notice that I've removed the pointer in my implementation. I do really prefer to use scoped variables whenever possible and recommend you to do so. It is an easy way of acquiring and releasing resources that will save you from the need of taking care of destruction.